# Finding time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion

I am to find the time complexity of my algorithm and I found one method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).
However I am really not sure about it correctness thus I would like to check it.
There is my algorithm (N is a set (len(N) is constant) and C is a number):

```
def f(N, C, k = 0):
    if C < 0:
        return 0
    if C == 0:
        return 1
    if not N:
        return 0
    i = 0
    for l in N:
        if l >= k:
            i += f(N, C - liczba, liczba)
    return i
```

And to my mind time complexity is equal to:
a+b+c+d+len(N)*C where a, b, c, d are constants.

Comment: How did you arrive at that result? Have you tried a [structured approach](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)?

Comment: I decided that each line of my code will be done in some time - those are a, b, c, d. Then we have the loop - l in N so len(N). And the function will be called (C - l) times.

Comment: @Hendrra As a matter of style, one would tend to merge all of those constants into one (the sum of a bunch of constants is just some other constant). However, the analysis is going to be much more complicated than you suggest, since each iteration of the loop makes a recursive call to `f`. (By the way, should `liczba` be `l`?)

Comment: Let m be the number of elements of N which are ≥ liczba. Each recursive call makes m recursive calls. The recursion will go about C / liczba levels deep, so the execution time is roughly m^(C / liczba). Looks like your algorithm is terribly, terribly inefficient, since the result can easily be found in time proportional to the number of elements of N plus C / liczba.

Comment: Just run the algorithm with N = { 1, 2 }, liczba = 1, and C going from 1 to 100 and measure the time (hint: your computer will not finish this task). It seems you haven't done this, or you would never, ever have the idea that the time would be just linear in C * len (N).